# Livecycle ES2 - making a script run that doesn't require exiting the field

Tags: javascript, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a read-only calculated field, and I want to build actions on it, dependent on what the answer to the calculated field is.

I have used action builder, and it works, but only if the form filler clicks in and out ("exits") the field, which they didn't have to enter in the first place, because it populates as a result of a previous script.

To be more precise, The questions asked before this field are:

Date of submission (submitdate):
Date of event (eventdate):

Calculation occurs (days between event and submission), and answer is populated in a field called 'daysbetween'

Now I have a set of conditions:

If the daysbetween is < or = 14, then I want a message to come up saying ineligible to apply
If the daysbetween is >14 and < or = 28, then I want a message to come up saying a fast track fee will be applied, and I want the fast track fee box to be populated, and I want the fast track fee box to appear.

I used the action builder to get all of this to work, except that it only works if the user then clicks in and out of  the 'daysbetween' field, which they shouldn't have to, because it's already calculated for them and populates when they exit the field before

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I were tasked with this, here's how I would approach it:

I would use the script editor as opposed to action builder.

- In my submitdate.change and my eventdate.change events I would call the daysbetween.calculate event
- In my daysbetween.calculate event I would do everything you need there including figuring out the number of days between the two dates, display a message if needed, and show and populate fast track fee box if needed.